# What happened when the ark hit the mountain with a fast speed?

Tags: plot-explanation, 2012

At the end of the movie *2012*, when one of the big ships was a few meters behind the mountain, they went with a very fast speed and hit the mountain. And then it says something like

> Day 27, Month 12, year 0001.

and everything went back to normal.

What exactly happened here? Where did they go? Did they time get reversed till the year 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did the time got reversed till Adam and Eve?

## No

This is to indicate that they have started a new era so they stopped using the old year numbering system and began a new era starting  with "Year 1".

> What exactly happened? / Where did they go?

The ships floated for almost month (27 days to be precise) and [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_(film)) explains

> Twenty-seven days later, the waters are receding. The arks approach the **Cape of Good Hope**, where the Drakensberg (now the tallest mountain range on Earth) is emerging.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to type in my answer, the date actually marked beginning  of a new era and the only continent left above water was that of Africa as seen by top view of the earth.